# Use Git Commands in Jenkins: git not found

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm running Jenkins on Kubernetes with the git plugin installed. 
Now I want to use git commands in my script, which fails with the log:

```
script.sh: line 1: git: not found
```

My script:

```
stage('Package Helm Chart'){
            sh """ 
              #!/bin/bash

              echo "Pushing to remote Repository.."

              git checkout master

              git add <myfilehere>

              git commit -m "[Jenkins] Adding Artifact ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} to repository"

              git push

              echo "Successfully pushed artifact to repository"
            """
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Cheers 
Jst

Comment: does the git plugin actually install git or just make an installed git available to jenkins? so maybe you need to install git seperately

Answer (score 5):

The sh command in question should run on a jenkins node inside a node block. This command will then run in a shell on that node. To use git in the sh tag of a pipeline script you need to have git installed and on the PATH on the node that you want to use.

If you are using Kubernetes, then I assume you are running the Jenkins master or the node from a docker image, thus this image will need git installed and on the PATH.

Once this is done the shell will be able to find git.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you mix Jenkins git plugin, that allow you to choose git as source code management for project workspace Inside project configuration, and git in command line Inside a script that which requires that git is install and present in $PATH when script is execute.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was caused by unintentional error in the groovy code, i had written **sh** while i actually want to write **echo** for debugging purpose, removed it and Jenkins job ran successfully.

```
stage("Deploy"){
  steps{
    ----
    //sh "Deployment successful" - this resulted in script.sh: git not found error
    echo "Deployment successful" - this fixed it.
  }
}
```

strange but true... this could help someone who might be doing same mistake as that of mine.